# Kubernetes not restarting failed pods on another docker node

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a 4 node kubernetes cluster with 3 minions. I am running the application with 2 replica pods on the two minion node. When the docker engine on one of the minion stops, kubernetes shows the status of pods running on that docker node as error and does not restart the pod on the other minion node. Is there any way, kubernetes will try to restart failed pods on the nodes available in the cluster?

Comment: take look about resistant in kubernetes.

Comment: Sorry there was typo. Kubernetes not starting failed pod on other available docker node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes not scheduling failed pod on other node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733478/kubernetes-not-scheduling-failed-pod-on-other-node)