# Kubernetes not scheduling failed pod on other node

Tags: kubernetes

I have 4 nodes kubernetes cluster. My application running with 2 replica instances. I am using deployment resource with replica set. As per the documentation , replica set always ensure that specified no. Of application instances will be running.If I delete the one pod instance, then it will be restarted on the same or different node.But when I simulated the failure of a pod instance by stopping docker engine on one node. Kubectl shows status as error for the pod instance but do not restart the pod on another node. Is it the expected behaviour or am I missing something.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIS Kubernetes changed that behavior with version 1.5. If I interpret the [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b0ce93f9be25c762fd4b746077fcda2aaa5b12bd/CHANGELOG.md#notable-changes-to-existing-behavior) correctly, the Pods of the failed node is still registered in the apiserver, since it abruptly died and wasn't able to unregister the pods. Since the Pod is still registered, the ReplicaSet doesn't replace it.

The reason for this is, that Kubernetes cannot tell if it is a network error (eg split-brain) or a node failure. With StatefulSets being introduced, Kubernetes needs to make sure that no Pod is started more than one time.

This maybe sounds like a bug, but if you have a properly configured cloud-provider (eg for GCE or AWS), Kubernetes can see if that Node is still running. When you would shut down that node, the controller should unregister the Node and its Pods and then create a new Pod on another Node. Together with a Node health check and a Node replacement, the cluster is able to heal itself.

How the cloud-provider is configured depends highly on your Kubernetes setup.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using Kubernetes 1.5.4. I checked the doc link and it is applicable for statefulset. For all controllers except statefulset, this has no effect on the ability of the controller to replace pods because the controllers do not reuse pod names (they use generate-name).

Also I have in house kubernetes cluster deployed on ubuntu vms.

Comment: Is the node still listed in `kubectl get nodes`? Can you try to delete the failed node and see what happens?

Comment: Also the change "Node controller no longer force-deletes pods from the api-server." is for all kind of Pods and if the controller isn't able to delete a Pod, it is still a valid replica. At least from my experience the behavior changed with 1.5.

Comment: Deleting the node also not restarting the pods. Only deleting pods causing rescheduling of pods.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately then I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for about 5 mins of bringing down the node or docker on it. Kubernetes marks the status of all the pods which were running on that node as 'Unknown' and will bring them up on the remaining active eligible nodes. Once the failed node comes back up, the pods on that node would be deleted if K8S already has them replaced on other node(s).